# PHP - How to split string into array by regular expression at whitespace and html tag?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, preg-split

Here is a example string:

```
$string = '<strong>Lorem ipsum dolor</strong> sit <img src="test.png" /> amet <span class="test" style="color:red">consec<i>tet</i>uer</span>.';
```

I want to split the string into array such that the string get split whenever a whitespace is hit or an html tag is hit (ignoring whitespace inside html tag). For Example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <strong>
    [1] => Lorem
    [2] => ipsum
    [3] => dolor
    [4] => </strong>
    [5] => sit
    [6] => <img src="test.png" />
    [7] => amet
    [8] => <span class="test" style="color:red">
    [9] => consec
    [10] => <i>
    [11] => tet
    [12] => </i>
    [13] => uer
    [14] => </span>
    [15] => .
)
```

But i am unable to achieve this. I used [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to achieve this idea but i think i am mistaken in my regular expressions. Below are some expressions i tried but the results are not what i want.

```
$chars = preg_split('/(<[^>]*[^\/]>)/i', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

/* Results */

Array
(
    [0] => <strong>
    [1] => Lorem ipsum dolor
    [2] => </strong>
    [3] =>  sit <img src="test.png" /> amet 
    [4] => <span class="test" style="color:red">
    [5] => consec
    [6] => <i>
    [7] => tet
    [8] => </i>
    [9] => uer
    [10] => </span>
    [11] => .
)
```

and the result of other regular expression is:

```
$chars = preg_split('/\s+(?![^<>]*>)/x', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

/* Results */
Array
(
    [0] => <strong>Lorem
    [1] => ipsum
    [2] => dolor</strong>
    [3] => sit
    [4] => <img src="test.png" />
    [5] => amet
    [6] => <span class="test" style="color:red">consec<i>tet</i>uer</span>.
)
```

and the result of another expression is (quite close):

```
$chars = preg_split('/\s*(<[^>]*>)/i', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

/* Results */
Array
(
    [0] => <strong>
    [1] => Lorem ipsum dolor
    [2] => </strong>
    [3] =>  sit
    [4] => <img src="test.png" />
    [5] =>  amet
    [6] => <span class="test" style="color:red">
    [7] => consec
    [8] => <i>
    [9] => tet
    [10] => </i>
    [11] => uer
    [12] => </span>
    [13] => .
)
```

Comment: [`array_filter(preg_split('~(<[^>]*>)|\s+~i', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE))`](https://ideone.com/MWP2DS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost near to get it. But you need to change `<[^>]*>` to a more specific regex `<\/?\w+[^<>]*>` then you need to set an alternation for whitespaces `|\s+`. You don't need `i` flag either:

```
preg_split('/(<\/?\w+[^<>]*>)|\s+/', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Got the result as wanted. :)